# Is it possible in Javascript to fire an event when someone clicks a flashobject

Tags: javascript, flash, embed

We use a video player on our site which gives us the following embed code

```
<object width="640" height="390" id="gorillanationPlayer_sotv002_playlist_677_sotv002_single_302479" data="http://cdn.springboard.gorillanation.com/storage/xplayer/yo033.swf?pid=sotv002&siteId=677&videoId=302479&autostart=false&file=http://cms.springboard.gorillanation.com/xml_feeds_advanced/index/677/3/302479/" class="SpringboardSwitcher" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"> <param name="wmode" value="transparent"> <param name="swliveconnect" value="true"> <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"> <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"> <param name="movie" value="http://cdn.springboard.gorillanation.com/storage/xplayer/yo033.swf?pid=sotv002&siteId=677&videoId=302479&autostart=false&file=http://cms.springboard.gorillanation.com/xml_feeds_advanced/index/677/3/302479/"></object>
```

Is it possible to detect when someone clicks on the object to play it? I'd like to capture an event to fire off some other Javascript. Any ideas welcomed.

Cheers

Comment: Do you have control over the source code of the SWF file?

Comment: No, I'm afraid all we get is the Embed Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use ExternalInterface to call your javascript:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html